# How to disable weak-ciphers on rmi port on Jboss 4.2.3GA?

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, jboss, rmi

I don't have any service connector port setting for rmi in file `/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/server.xml`. I have an mbean for `org.jboss.invocation.jrmp.server.JRMPInvoker` in `/conf/jboss-service.xml` in which I have settings for ports, server address, etc. How do I specify cipher-suites for rmi so that I am able to disable week ciphers (less than 128 bits). I used [sslscan](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sslscan/) to check what all ciphers were accepted on the rmi port and there were 5 cipher-suites which are less than 128 that were accepted.